# Xamarin forms labs : System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: mono, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting the following **error** after updating Xamarin Forms to 1.3.1 version.
 Also tried with updating `Xamarin.Forms.Labs to 1.2.1 pre2`, its also not helping.

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.OnDestroy () <IL 0x0002d, 0x000d8>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Droid.XFormsApplicationDroid.OnDestroy () [0x0001f] in c:\Users\rmarinho\Documents\GitHub\Xamarin-Forms-Labs\src\Xamarin.Forms.Labs\Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Droid\XFormsApp.cs:61
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnDestroy (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-17/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2524
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.e36a43a7-84b6-4476-8a62-6959a3b43e6a (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
```

Any help on how to fix this error?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Having the same issue here.
Have you managed to resolve it?

Comment: No. I stick with Xamarin.Forms 1.2.3 and XFLabs 1.2.0 for now. @SamAleksov

Comment: XLabs 2.0-pre3 pushed into Nuget today with XF 1.3.1 support.

Comment: I've compiled the XLabs 2.0 from source and the error is still there...

Comment: Have you Called in your MainActivity to LoadApplication(YourCustomApplication)?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I get the same error.

Comment: After XF 1.4.0 update, i am not getting the error

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code of `FormsApplicationActivity` and it looks like you're disposing your object somehow before assigning a Page to it (or at least that's one mode of failure I think is possible).

Share your code with us for a more detail solution, but basically try setting the App's main page before disposing.